# Why can primitives not be stored in Java collections, but primitive arrays can?

Tags: java

```
List<int> list; //compile-time error
List<int[]> list1; //works fine
```

Is there any reason for this behavior? I know primitives need to be boxed but why not primitive arrays?

Comment: Because arrays of any type are objects, not primitives.

Comment: because every array represent a class

Comment: `array` is always an object so no problem to keep that generic in list.. If I am not wrong we have auto cASTINGthing even if you keep premitive it will auto cast it to its wrapper class..

Comment: Note that this question is explicitly asking about *arrays,* not primitives.

Comment: @Sotorius Delimanolis OP knows the primitive issue so I dont think its a duplicate.OP has a problem second part ie array type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Java arrays are objects, not primitives. And you can store references to objects in Java collections implemented as generic types.

From the [Java language specification, Chapter 10: Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html):

> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object (§4.3.2). All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array.

Note that arrays and generics don't always play well together. Although you *can* create a collection of arrays, you *can't* create an array of collections. Type-checking of array contents is performed at run time. But the parameterized types of collections are not known at run time, because of type erasure. From Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java," 2nd ed., *"Item 25: Prefer lists to arrays"*:

> For example, it is illegal to create an array of generic type, a parameterized type, or a type parameter. None of these array creation expressions are legal: `new List<E>[], new List<String>[], new E[]`. All will result in *generic array creation* errors at compile time.